# How to use a proxy with google cloud libraries

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-monitoring

My code is in an environment that has egress restrictions therefore I need to go through a proxy in order to connect to the outside world. Does google cloud libraries have the ability to pass in a proxy and connect via that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Client libraries do not offer a built in proxy support. You will have to configure a system proxy or environment specific proxy.

For example, if you're running a JVM you can configure the proxy settings as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

Golang also [supports something similar](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go).